# What hop will give me grapefruit-like aroma?

Tags: hops, aroma, wheat-beer

I'll be making American Wheat beer this weekend. Simple malt bill - half wheat, half barley. I'm planning to use Chinook for bitterness. What would go well with it's resin and "coniferous forest" quality, to add a bit of citrus taste and grapefruit aroma? I'm open to dry hopping and don't mind using different hops for last minutes of boil and dry addition. I just don't know which ones to use.

My bets so far was:

- Centennial
- Cascade
- Simcoe

Is any of them any good for this purpose? In this specific combination?

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: @BoilerBrad accepting is not mandatory, and, since I can't use Citra, I do want to keep this open for other answers, hop combinations etc. I appreciate your answer and upvoted it, but clicking accpet mark when in fact I'll not test it seems weird. I came from programming stack, where accept mark means "I have tested it" and I have strong feelings against accepting somethings I did  not test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Citra is a good bet for grapefruit aromas. Check this link for a nice tool to help with hopping your beers

https://www.hopunion.com/aroma-wheel/

Comment: Good advice. Only reason I forgot Citra is the fact that it's simply unavailable in my area now. You got my upvote.

Comment: Cascade can work. I would avoid Simcoe since it has more of a piney aroma imo.

Answer (score 2):

Centennial will give a pronounced grapefruit flavor.